# How to modify the Firebase database structure (for testing) without causing problems at the client's side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have already published my app on Google Play, and I use the structure (shown in the figure) to store users' data on Firebase. I had also defined a "FirebaseUserData" class in my app, and at the client's side, each user downloads his/her data using:

```
FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseUserData.class);
```

The problem is that now I want to add a "score" node under each userUID and TEST my app -- but that way, the whole structure of the database would be changed, and users can no longer download their data since the database structure does not FIT the FirebaseUserData.class anymore.

Any way I can modify the firebase database structure without causing any problem at the clients' side?

Comment: Export current database. Create new firebase project. Import existing database. Update client code for the new project and test freely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate build variant for testing via `productFlavors`.
2. In new build variant change `applicationId`
3. Add separate project in Firebase and move there existing database.